# Highcharts - Show a string category label in the tooltip for a line graph

Tags: user-interface, graph, highcharts, line-plot

I have a [line graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cWuhB.png) already plotted. Each point also has a sensitivity (a categorical label). Either null, "Low", "Medium", "High"

For now, my data is just in a JSON object at the top. The `sensitivities` key is formatted like this: [timestamp, sensitivity label]

When I hover over a point, I want to show the sensitivity label under `Value` in the tooltip if there is a sensitivity label. Thanks for any help.

Here's a jsfiddle I'm working with: https://jsfiddle.net/keshprad_dev/ny9f14vq/

Answer (score 0):

Use tooltip formatter function, find matched sensitivities data by x value and add it to a tooltip string. Example:

```
tooltip: {
  ...,
  formatter: function(tooltip) {
    const rows = tooltip.defaultFormatter.call(this, tooltip);
    const matchedSen = graphData.sensitivities.find(s => s[0] === this.x);

    if (matchedSen && matchedSen[1]) {
      rows.push(['Sensitivities: ' + matchedSen[1]]);
    }

    return rows;
  }
}
```

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/Lx2fz3m0/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.formatter